# How to check if this is a metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbf{B}$ be the set of bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. If $a= (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $b= (b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$,

Define:
$d_{\infty}(a,b) = sup\{|a_n-b_n|: n\in\mathbb{N} \}$

Exercise: Check that $d_{\infty}$ is a metric on $\mathbf{B}$.

I checked for positivity and symmetry, but I'm struggling a little with the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the tringle inequality for this supremum norm, for $a,b,c\in {\bf B}$ you can write the componentwise tringle inequality (for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$):
$$|a_n-c_n|\leq |a_n-b_n|+|b_n-c_n|, \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N},$$
and then take supremum in the right order:
$$ \Rightarrow |a_n-c_n|\leq |a_n-b_n|+d_\infty(b,c), \quad \forall n \in\mathbb{N},$$
$$ \Rightarrow |a_n-c_n|\leq d_\infty(a,b)+d_\infty(b,c), \quad \forall n \in\mathbb{N}, $$ $$ \Rightarrow d_\infty(a,c)\leq d_\infty(a,b)+d_\infty(b,c), \quad \forall n \in\mathbb{N}. $$
That's all.

Answer (score 2):

Take three bounded sequences $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

By the triangle inequality, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$ \lvert a_n - c_n\rvert \leq \lvert a_n - b_n\rvert+\lvert b_n - c_n\rvert$$
and so, taking the supremum, 
$$
\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \lvert a_n - c_n\rvert \leq \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left( \lvert a_n - b_n\rvert+\lvert b_n - c_n\rvert\right).
$$
Now, observe that
$$
\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left( \lvert a_n - b_n\rvert+\lvert b_n - c_n\rvert\right) \leq \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \lvert a_n - b_n\rvert+  \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \lvert b_n - c_n\rvert
$$
to conclude.

---

If you are unclear on that last step: you can for instance prove it as follows.

> For every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$
>   $$\sup_n(x_n + y_n) \leq \sup_n x_n + \sup_n y_n.$$
>   *Proof.*
>   For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
>   $$x_n + y_n \leq x_n + \sup_m y_m$$
>   so that, taking the supremum,
>   $$\sup_n\left( x_n + y_n\right) \leq \sup_n\left( x_n + \sup_m y_m\right) = \sup_n x_n + \sup_m y_m = \sup_n x_n+ \sup_n y_n.$$
>   (In the middle step, we used the fact that $\sup_m y_m$ is "just a number," independent of $n$: namely, $\sup_n(x_n+\alpha) = \sup_n x_n + \alpha$.)

Comment: Awesome reply, thank you so much! I don't however understand why we're operating with $\sup_m y_m$ and why later $\sup_m y_m = \sup_n y_n$.

Comment: For the latter: $n,m$ are dummy variables there. It is the same reason as for which $\int f(y)dy = \int f(x)dx=\int f(t)dt$, or $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k = \sum_{n=0} a_n$: the "name" of the variable is arbitrary. As for the former: this is, at its core, exactly the same proof as in the answer you accepted, with additional details. you have two terms, $x_n+y_n$; you write that $y_n \leq \sup_m y_m$, so that $x_n+y_n \leq x_n + \sup_m y_m$.